# How does the Alternative Favored Class bonus work for a Halfling Sorcerer Arcane Bloodline?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, halfling

**How does the Alternative Favored Class bonus work for a Halfling Sorcerer Arcane Bloodline?**

If I choose Sorcerer as my favored class I'm entitled to +1 hit point, +1 skill rank, or another race and class specific benefit as added in the Advanced Player's Guide.

If my character is a Halfling Sorcerer with the Arcane Bloodline the Halflings "Favored Class Option" for sorcerer is:

> Sorcerer Select one bloodline power at 1st level that is normally
>   usable a number of times per day equal to 3 + the sorcerer's Charisma
>   modifier. The sorcerer adds +1/2 to the number of uses per day of that
>   bloodline power.

the problem is that the 1st level Arcane Bloodline Power is familiar bond which has no "usable a number of times...", and neither does the 3rd, 9th, 15th or 20th level Bloodline Powers.

Does this mean I don't have the option of using the "another race and class specific benefit as added" each time I level up?

Comment: That is a tough one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you choose the Arcane bloodline then no, there are no bloodline powers that the Halfling favoured class option can apply to. But this doesn't mean that you don't gain **any** bonuses for sorcerer being your favoured class, you just fall back to the standard options. You can only chose the +1 hit point or skill rank per level.

If you wanted to use the Halfling's favoured class option then you would have to choose a different blood line, one with a power that meets the requirements, such as Celestial (Heavenly Fire power).

Comment: Thx... this is what I was looking for.